# How to include SQL Compact and .NET Framework in my Installer

Tags: .net, installation, sql-server-ce

I need to have my installer include the .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 as well as SQL Compact 3.5.  I remember seeing a place somewhere in the Visual Studio IDE where these could be included in the install, but I can't find them.  Does anyone know how to do this?  Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a Smart Device installer with CF 3.5 and SQL Server CE included?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217751/how-to-create-a-smart-device-installer-with-cf-3-5-and-sql-server-ce-included)

Answer (score 1):

Found it!  It looks like you can go to the "Properties" window of the Installer project and click on the "Prerequisites" button to see a list of prerequisite installers to include in your installer like SQL Server, SQL Compact, .NET Framework versions, etc.

It appears that the list is driven off of things that you have installed on the development computer.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to register for redistribution rights:

http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/compact-redistribute.aspx